# Посоветуйте плагин wordpess для фильтрации постов по таксономиям

Tags: filter, wp-plugin

В процессе изучения wordpess, делаю сайт для агенства недвижимости. Нужно реализовать фильтр объектов по районам, цене, квадратуре и тд. Есть ли какие-нибудь плагины, которыми можно это сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можете использовать такой плагин, очень хороший https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/wp-meta-data-filter-and-taxonomy-filter/, но кажется будет лучше, если вы все таки по таксономии сделаете стандартный фильтр, заложенный уже в сам движок. Тут дается описание как сделать https://misha.blog/wordpress/filtryi-zapisey-i-tovarov.html

Comment: Спасибо большое!!)